# SQL - find missing records in each date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

1. A product table that has productID of all products (productName, productID)
2. A transaction table of records with columns: date (for last 3 months) and productID. All productID should have at least one record for each date.

However, there are missing productID records for some datss, and I would like to find the missing productID and the respective dates they are missing from.

Right now, I'm only able to find missing records for one particular date, which is:

```
Select productName, productID
from product a inner join transaction b
On a.productid=b.productid
Where a.productid not in 
    (
    Select distinct productid
    From transaction
    Where date='2019-03-01'
    )
```

I would like to have a table that consolidates all dates and their respective missing productid records. How can I proceed from here?

```
    create table product
    (ProductID INT,
    ProductName Char (30)
     );

    insert into product values 
    (1, 'apple'), 
    (2, 'orange'), 
    (3, 'pear'); 

    create table transaction1 
    (transDate Date, 
    productID INT, 
    revenue FLOAT); 

    insert into transaction1 values 
    ('2019-03-01', 1, 2.5), 
    ('2019-03-01', 2, 4.0), 
    ('2019-03-01', 2, 8.0), 
    ('2019-03-01', 3, 6.0), 
    ('2019-03-02', 1, 7.0), 
    ('2019-03-02', 3, 14.0), 
    ('2019-03-03', 1, 1.5) ;
```

What i have will be similar to this, where productID=2 is missing from 03-02. I am working for dates from beginning of the year till yesterday, which are all recorded in the transaction table.
@SimonPrice

Comment: Can you go to SQLFIddle and create recreate the issue so that we can help you. it only needs to be a minimal example, however, give 20 records in each table so that we know what youre working with.  Are you looking to do this in a date range or specific date or multiple dates or ranges?

Comment: HINT: Use a full outer join and look for NULL in productid.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: @mkRabbani sorry, could you elaborate on this question? the database i am using contains multiple tables, and the two tables i am using are just a small part of that database. I am using microsoft SQL server 2012

Comment: Got your answer "microsoft SQL server 2012" :) you should tag this database in your question which helps other.

Comment: @mkRabbani have tagged. thank you! :)

Comment: @Namphibian 

`select distinct a.productID, productName, transdate
from product a full outer join transaction b
on a.productid=b.productid
where a.productid=null`

does not return any null values. are my select values wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most tricky part of your problem is to generate the list of all dates for your expected date which is 90 days in your case. Here I have created all dates using a loop. One additional column 'Common' added with value 1 to Product and Temp table to join with the product table for all date and all product.

**Note:** Just change the value of @HowManyDay as per days you wants to check.

```
DECLARE @HowManyDay INT
SET @HowManyDay = 8
DECLARE @LoopCount INT
SET @LoopCount = 0 


DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(Common INT,All_Date DATE)

WHILE @LoopCount <=  @HowManyDay-1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable (Common,All_Date)
    VALUES (1,DATEADD(DD,-@LoopCount,GETDATE()))

    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1
END

SELECT  B.All_Date,C.productID,C.productName,T.date
FROM @TempTable B
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 [Common],* 
    FROM product
)C ON B.Common = C.Common
LEFT JOIN transaction_details T ON C.productID = T.productID AND B.All_Date = T.date
WHERE T.date IS NULL
ORDER BY 3 ASC,1 DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the answer to my problem :)

Comment: @Tan You are most welcome. you can also give me a up-vote for this :)

Comment: have upvoted but unfortunately i have less than 15 reputation so it will not be displayed, sorry. Thanks again!

Comment: Its fine my dear :)